# Need help on this query

Tags: email, comparison

I want to have a output count as 2 for the user_mail logged as test1@gmail.com for a query like this,

```
SELECT Count(user_refemai) from Table_users where userref_mail = user_mail
```

but, I'm getting the output as 0! What am I doing wrong?

My table_users looks like:

```
user_id         user_mail               user_refemail  
1               test1@gmail.com         NULL    
2               test2@gmail.com         test1@gmail.com  
3               test3@gmail.com         test1@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

you are getting 0 as in your query the condition is false all the time

for this purpose you have to use the cursor or inner queries and then get the count
or pass the parameter to the query for which you want to get the counts.

Answer (score 0):

Shafqat is correct.  To build on that, you'd pass in the query parameter like this:

```
SELECT count(*)
    FROM
        table_users
    WHERE
        userref_email = ?
```

If you need a reporting query instead of for a particular email address, you could use a self join.